# Why $\max \left\{ {{x^T}Ax:x \in {R^n},{x^T}x = 1} \right\}$ is the largest real eigenvalue of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $A \in {M_n}(R)$ and A is symmetric.Why $\max \left\{ {{x^T}Ax:x \in {R^n},{x^T}x = 1} \right\}$ is the largest real eigenvalue of A?

Comment: The thing is that you can find a matrix $U$ such that $U^tU=I$ and $U^tAU$ is diagonal.Then make the change of variable $x=Uy$.

Comment: Are you aware of the spectral theorem?

Answer (score 7):

You can try to maximize the function $f:\mathbb{R}{^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(\mathbb{x}) = {\mathbb{x}^T}\mathbf{A}\mathbb{x}$ using standard calculus and see what you get. Since we are trying to maximize 
$f$ subject to the condition  ${\mathbb{x}^T}\mathbb{x} = 1$, using the Lagrange multiplier technique, we need to find the critical points of
$$g(\mathbb{x},\lambda) = {\mathbb{x}^T}\mathbf{A}\mathbb{x} - \lambda ({\mathbb{x}^T}\mathbb{x} - 1)$$
Deriving with respect to $\mathbb{x}=[x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n]^T$ and setting the derivative equal to zero
$${{\partial g} \over {\partial \mathbb{x}}} = 0 \Leftrightarrow 2\mathbf{A}\mathbb{x} - 2\lambda \mathbb{x} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \mathbf{A}\mathbb{x} = \lambda \mathbb{x}$$
we see that $\mathbb{x}$ should be an eigenvector of $\mathbf{A}$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Plugging this information back into our function $f$, we get
$f(\mathbb{x})={\mathbb{x}^T}\mathbf{A}\mathbb{x} = {\mathbb{x}^T}\lambda \mathbb{x} =\lambda {\mathbb{x}^T}\mathbb{x} = \lambda$ so in order to maximize $f$, we should take for $\lambda$ the largest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$.

By ${{\partial g} \over {\partial \mathbb{x}}}$, I denote the vector of partial derivatives of $$g({x_1},{x_2},...,{x_n},\lambda) = \sum\limits_{i,j = 1}^n {{a_{ij}}{x_i}{x_j}}  - \lambda \left( {\sum\limits_{l = 1}^n {x_l^2}  - 1} \right)$$ with respect to every component of $\mathbb{x}$. For example, the $k-$th component of ${{\partial g} \over {\partial \mathbb{x}}}$ is given by
$${{\partial g} \over {\partial {x_k}}} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_{ik}}{x_i}}  + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {{a_{kj}}{x_j}}  -2 \lambda x_k= 2\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{a_{ki}}{x_i}} -2 \lambda x_k$$
Here we use the fact that $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric.

Note that the function $f$ is unbounded if the norm of $\mathbb{x}$ is not constrained.

Answer (score 2):

- Let $f(x)=x^TAx$. Then $f(x)$ is continuous on the compact set $C:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:x^Tx=1\}$. By the Weierstrass's theorem $f(x)$ attains its maximum on $C$.
- Since $A$ is symmetric, $A$ has $n$ real eigenvalue $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Put
  $$
  \lambda:=\max\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n\}.
  $$
- Let $u$ be the eigenvector of matrix $A$ with the respective eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $u^Tu=1$.Then
  $$
  \max\{x^TAx:x^Tx=1\}\geq u^TAu=u^t(\lambda u)=\lambda u^tu=\lambda. \quad \textbf{(1)}
  $$
- By the diagonalization, there exists nonsingular matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $B^{-1}=B^T$ and
  $$
  \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n)=BAB^{-1}.
  $$
- Let $x$ such that $x^Tx=1$. Then,
  \begin{eqnarray*}
  x^TAx&=&x^T(B^{-1}BAB^{-1}B)x\\
  &=&(x^TB^T)\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n)(Bx)\\
  &=&y^T\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n)y
  \end{eqnarray*}
  where $y=Bx$.
- Note that $y^Ty=(Bx)^TBx=x^TB^TBx=x^Tx=1$. Let $y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$. Then
  $$
  1=y^Ty=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2.
  $$
  It follows that
  $$
  x^TAx=y^T\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n)y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_iy_i^2\leq\lambda\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2\leq\lambda.\quad \textbf{(2)}
  $$
  Combining **(1)** and **(2)** we obtain
  $$
  \max\{x^TAx:x^Tx=1\}=\max
  \{\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n\}.
  $$

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is symmetric so it can be orthogonally diagonalized using a unitary matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ containing the eigenvalues as diagonal entries. $A = P D P^T$. Let $y = P^T x$, then $\max \{x^T A x: x^Tx = 1\} = \max \{ y^T D y: y^T y = 1 \}$ (using the unitarity of $P$). It is easily seen from the properties of $D$ that $\max \{ y^T D y: y^T y = 1 \}$ is equal to the largest diagonal entry of $D$ which is the largest eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's an intuitive and somewhat geometric explaination of what is happening. 
$1:$ For $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue, we need to be able to find a vector $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$ 
$2:$ We observe that $v$ is an eigenvector iff $v\over{||v||}$ is an eigenvector.  So, we reduce the search space to the unit sphere.ie., vectors with norm $=1$. So, now we have to find $\lambda$ and $v$ such that $Av=\lambda v$ and $||v||=1$
$3:$ Since we are talking about symmetric matrices existence of eigenvalues is guaranteed. Our claim now is that the largest eigenvalue is given by $max_{||x||=1} x^TAx$. 
 
$4:$Observe here that $y=Ax$ is a vector. It need not lie on the unit sphere. But we are projecting $y$ onto a vector $x$ in the unit sphere by taking $x^Ty$. 
$5: $ When is this maximized ? 
 
By the definition of standard dot product, if $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$,  $x^Ty=||x||||y||cos(\theta)=||y||cos(\theta)$. Here, for a given $x$, this would have been maximized when $cos(\theta)=1$. Since the existence of eigenvalues is guaranteed, this definitely occurs at the eigenvectors.The maximum among these is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue.
 As for vectors which are not eigenvectors,we can directly see that $x^Ty<||y||$. Now, because $A$ is diagonalizable and the eigenvectors $v_1,...,v_n$ form a basis, we can write $x=\alpha_1v_1 + ... + \alpha_nv_n$.Here, we denote the largest eigenvalue by $\lambda_1$ and the corresponding eigenvector to be $v_1$ . So, $Ax=\alpha_1\lambda_1v_1 + ... + \alpha_n\lambda_nv_n$. $||y||=||Ax||\leq||\alpha_1\lambda_1v_1 + ... + \alpha_n\lambda_1v_n||=\lambda_1||x||=\lambda_1$. So, those which are not eigenvectors donot exceed this value.

Comment: Very good intuition. I think when you write "existence of eigenvalues is guaranteed" you are talking about real eigenvalues. In your proof the symmetricity of $A$ is not used other than its eigenvalues being real and eigenvectors are linearly independent. So does this claim hold for any real-eigenvalued diagonalizable matrix?

Comment: Use $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ for example. It has eigenvectors $(1, 1)$ for $\lambda=2$ and $(1,0)$ for $\lambda=1$. However, according to Wolfram|Alpha, the maximum value of $x^T A x$ when $||x||=1$ is somewhere around 2.2, which is bigger than 2. So what am I missing here?

Comment: @obareey Thanks for the comment.There is another place where symmetricity is used. In the last step, we are able to say that $||Ax||\leq\lambda_1||x||$ only because $A=A^*$.This is bcoz' $||A||_2=\sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^*A)}$. Further details can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm . In fact, I didn't realize this till you raised the question and was just lucky that actually the step could be justified. Thanks a lot for that.